# Send transactional email: first user's post

Tags: author, email

I want to add this piece of code to my functions.php file, so that when a user creates its first post, he receives an email to congratulate him.

```
function set_mail_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'author_publish_notice', 10 ,2 );

function author_publish_notice( $ID, $post ) {
    if( 'post' == $post->post_type && count_user_posts(the_author_meta('ID') == 1); ) {
        return;
    }
    $to = 'author@email.com';
    $subject = 'Your Article Is Online';
    $message = '<h1>Congratulations!</h1> <p>Your article is now online and 
        is sure to receives trillions of comments. Please do hang around and answer any questions
        viewers may have!</p> <p><a href="' . get_permalink( $ID ) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></p>';

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type' );
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message ); 
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type' );

}
```

However, I have a doubt about this line:

```
$to = 'author@email.com';
```

To retrieve the author's email, the codex shows this:

```
 <?php the_author_email(); ?>
```

Would this make sense? :

```
$to = the_author_email();
```

Also, it this enough to add the condition that the post is the first post of the author:

```
if( 'post' == $post->post_type && count_user_posts(the_author_meta('ID') == 1); )
```

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close - let's take a look at this line:

```
if( 'post' == $post->post_type && count_user_posts(the_author_meta('ID') == 1); )
```

1. That semicolon is a syntax error, PHP will barf - let it go
2. `the_author_meta()` *prints* data, it does not return anything - use `get_the_author_meta()` for comparisons and passing things around
3. The post count comparison needs to be *outside* the function call - note the difference in parentheses positions: `count_user_posts( $id ) == 1`, not `count_user_posts( $id == 1 )`

Having said all that, I get the impression this condition (when corrected) is the reverse of what you want - at the moment you're trying to say "if the post type is `post` and the author has one post, **do nothing**", when actually you want the opposite(?)

In which case, here's what I think you're after:

```
if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type || count_user_posts( $post->post_author ) > 1 )
   return; // If the post is NOT a post, or the author has more than one post, bail
```

See how I've used `$post->post_author` too? That's the user ID. It's part of the post object, no need to use a function here (despite what I said about `get_the_author_meta()` earlier).

Lastly, the email: you can either use said author function, or grab the user object directly (which is what the former is wrapper around anyway):

```
$user_email = get_user_by( 'id', $post->post_author )->user_email;
```

All together now:

```
function author_publish_notice( $ID, $post ) {
    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type || count_user_posts( $post->post_author ) > 1 )
        return;

    $to = get_user_by( 'id', $post->post_author )->user_email;
    $subject = 'Your Article Is Online';
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html',
        'From: user@example.com',
    );

    $message = '<h1>Congratulations!</h1> <p>Your article is now online and 
    is sure to receives trillions of comments. Please do hang around and answer any questions
    viewers may have!</p> <p><a href="' . get_permalink( $ID ) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></p>';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
}
```

You'll see I've also removed the content type filter - [you can pass mail headers as a fourth parameter to `wp_mail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail), either line-break separated or as an array.

Comment: Very helpful and complete answer, thank you. However, I added this to my functions.php, tried with a newly created user and created a post, nothing happened. Where should I look for a mistake ? Since I don't get any error, I don't really know where to start

Comment: Works fine for me - did you definitely publish the post? And make sure you've still got the line `add_action( 'publish_post', 'author_publish_notice', 10 ,2 );`

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot it works fine now thank you. Any idea on how to change the sending email address ? Right now it is wordpress@mysite.com

Comment: Use the headers - see update.